# How to wait for the result from a for loop in Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, for-loop, async-await

I have a for loop in typescript. The return result from the loop will be used as a parameter for another method. No matter how I tried, my code always returned a result before the end of the loop done. How a long enough wait time should be set so as to get the return result after the loop ends? Or any other solution would be appreciated.

```js
private async findMainItemId() {
    let mainItem = {id: 1, price: 0};
    mainItem.id = this.itemIds[0];
    
    for (let i = 0; i <= this.itemIds.length; i ++)
    {      
      this.checkoutService.getShippingFees(this.itemIds[i]).subscribe((resp: IDeliveryType[]) => {
        let itemDeliveryTypes = resp.filter(s => s.applied === true);
        let standardPrice = itemDeliveryTypes.find(dt => dt.name === 'standard').price;
          
        if ( standardPrice > mainItem.price) 
        {
          mainItem.id = this.itemIds[i].id;
          mainItem.price = standardPrice;
        };  
      })
    } 
    return mainItem.id;
  }
```

Comment: have tried using `await` in the code that calls this method? do you need to `await` for the `subscribe` method in this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `subscribe` does not return a Promise, you can manually wrap the callback in a `Promise` constructor so that you can `await` it.

```
private async findMainItemId() {
  const mainItem = {id: 1, price: 0};
  mainItem.id = this.itemIds[0];
    
  for (const item of this.itemIds) {
    await new Promise(resolve =>
      this.checkoutService.getShippingFees(item).subscribe((resp: IDeliveryType[]) => {
        const itemDeliveryTypes = resp.filter(s => s.applied);
        const standardPrice = itemDeliveryTypes.find(dt => dt.name === 'standard').price;
          
        if (standardPrice > mainItem.price) {
          mainItem.id = item.id;
          mainItem.price = standardPrice;
        };
        resolve();
      })
    );
  } 
  return mainItem.id;
}
```

Comment: The solution absolutely works! Thank you so much Stoneheart!

Comment: Glad that the solution helped!